# breezejs: security regarding exposing all properties to client

Tags: breeze

Let's say we expose the following entity and its properties to a client application:

`Employee {firstname, lastname, address, socialSecurityNumber}`

In the client application, we display all or a subset of the properties depending on the user privileges.

However since we queried on the Employee entity, all of the properties were sent back to the client-application. So if we decided to hide the socialSecurityNumber from some users, they would still be able to see the value coming back from the server, just by checking the content of the response.

What approach should we take to prevent this ? Currently I'm thinking to use projections that would be different according to who's logged in....

But some insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Especially for sensitive data, only send what is absolutely required for the screen at hand, and only send data that the user is allow to see.  I would go the path of the Data Transfer Object or projections.

Answer (score 0):

What he (@NathanFisher) said.  You can also control the properties sent at the JSON serialization level.  For example, in JSON.NET you can [conditionally serialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) properties using a [ContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm).